# Knife project on subsurf-object leaves artifacts

Tags: modeling, modifiers, knife-tool

I have a plane with subsurf modifier, And a circle to cut(knife project) with. The hole is cut, but it leaves mesh(artifacts) inside of it.
[image: artifacts]

Creasing (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd>) works on the outer edges only, leaving the artifacts.
[image: with crease]

Why is this happening?

Comment: The knife tool is creating ngons, which don't work very well with subserf. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/89/599

Comment: As @gandalf3 pointed out, catmull clark subsurf prefers quads (the generated mesh will always be all quads). Subsurf also doesn't like sharp corners and concarve faces (the mesh will sometimes fold over itself). Also n-gons tesselation is somewhat unpredictable from a users perspective. That being said, why not use subsurf to make a square hole round like this: [http://www.pasteall.org/pic/77423](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/77423)? :o)

Comment: @user2859 Just a small detail, which probably isn't that important from an artistic perspective, but [subserfing a square does not tend towards a circle](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2844/599).

Comment: @gandalf3 I know. That is why I wrote "round" ;). It's just a suggestion for the example above and "usually" close enough. If it is not, then subsurf might not be the best way to do things in the first place.

Comment: You could also do something like this: http://www.pasteall.org/pic/77427

Comment: As noted above, you need additional supporting geometry if you want to use this tool with the subsurf modifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The knife tool is creating [ngons](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.63/BMesh#Create_faces_with_N-gons), which are faces with more than 4 vertices.

Ngons and tris do not work very well with the subdivision surface modifier. See [When should N-Gons be used, and when shouldn't they?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/89/599)

When working with subserf, you pretty much always want to use quads (faces with four vertices) exclusively.
Instead of *knife project*, you could make a rough circle shape out of quads and then use the subserf to round it out:

[image]

### What I did in the gif:

1. *Inset* the plane (<kbd>I</kbd>).
2. Then in edge select mode (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>), <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> on the edge ring created by the inset to deselect it.
3. Subdivide (<kbd>W</kbd>).
4. Switch to vertex select mode (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>) and delete the center vertex.
5. Make the inner loop circular with the *To sphere* operator (<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>), or the *circle* operator of the bundled *loop tools* addon.
6. Extrude the shape to make it 3D (if you want), and add a constraining loop cut to make the subserf stay closer to the shape of the base geometry (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to make the new cut aligned to the existing edge loops, and <kbd>F</kbd> to pick between the edge loops you want to align to).
7. Make the outer edges of the cube/plane sharp with *edge crease* (<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>).