# Repetitive carvings/holes around a sphere

Tags: modeling

I'm doing a spherical electromagnetic motor and I need to design a main ball fully covered of circular holes (all of the same size) so I put the neodymium magnets inside them. The sphere is going to be made on a 3D printer.

I just started with Blender but I think I will manage to make the circular carving but I do not know how to make it all around the ball.

Comment: Have a look at http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/56542/15543 in reverse, ie extrude in instead of out.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67334/how-to-turn-my-honeycomb-pattern-into-the-sphere

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5856/cutting-a-circular-hole-in-a-hollow-cylinder-without-distorting https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28103/creating-a-truck-exhaust-mesh/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/226729/torus-pipe-joint-3d-printing https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51233/perforated-plate/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65395/repetitive-carving-holes-around-sphere https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58811/grid-similar-to-a-manhole-cover https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30996/is-there-an-easy-way-to-

Answer (score 21):

You may do it by ***beveling*** the ***Ico Sphere*** and using the ***Solidify*** and ***Edge Split*** modifiers.
[image]

Add an ***Ico Sphere*** with 3 subdivisions.
[image]

Enable *face selection mode*, press <kbd>A</kbd> in *Edit Mode* to select the whole mesh. Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and drag the mouse outwards to bevel it. Select one of the hexagons, go to *Select*-->*Select Similar*-->*Polygon Sides*. Delete selected hexagons with <kbd>X</kbd>-->*Only Faces*.
[image]

Add ***Solidify Modifier*** and increase its *Thickness* value. Add the ***Subsurf Modifier*** below and give it some subdivisions. Apply the *Solidify Modifier*.
[image]

Add the ***Edge Split Modifier*** above *Subsurf* and set its *split angle* to 80 degrees (you may experiment with value for optimal result though).
[image]

Apply the *modifiers* and ***smooth*** the mesh in the *Edit* panel of the *Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>).
[image]

---

***EDIT:*** After @wchargin 's remark I experimented a bit and tried to solve it in another way.

Added an *Ico Sphere* with 3 subs, poked it with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and then beveled some vertices (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>).
[image]
[image]

Now the holes have much more dense geometry, which I hope may let them create perfect circles after subdividing.

Comment: Yeah, good idea. [Note, however, that these won't converge to perfect circles,](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2837/to-what-plane-curve-does-a-catmull-clark-subdivision-converge) in case that matters (e.g., if this is for a model to be 3D printed).

Comment: Your question is about subdividing a square. In this case it's hexagon, wich creates almost perfect circle after subdividing.

Comment: Closer, yes, but still not precise. At twelve subdivisions of a unit hexagon, the maximum radius is 0.83333, the mean radius is 0.83155, and the minimum radius is 0.82994. After this many iterations, I would be surprised if this were a convergence issue. Of course, these tolerances of ~0.5% are unlikely to matter for most hobbyist parts.

Comment: @wchargin Good point friend. I've added an edit to my answer, which shows another solution. Please check it out.