# How to distribute the objects on a sphere evenly?

Tags: mesh, particles, bezier-curves

I want to replicate this mesh - https://youtu.be/lBMhGZ-iprw?t=16m27s
[image]

I think the best way is using a particle system of cubes. So I need to create a sphere of simple circles. It is necessary that in each circle the vertices are at equal distance from each other. But I don't know how to create those circles.

Comment: May be helpful: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65395/repetitive-carvings-holes-around-a-sphere

Comment: Thx, but he used Ico sphere, and vertices are not aligned on a horizontal axis.

Comment: Possibly interesting: https://bendwavy.org/sphere.htm . Not listed there is a paper that I can't now find, a doctoral thesis at Univ New South Wales iirc, about partitioning the n-sphere into equal cells with lines of longitude and latitude.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it using both ***dupliverts*** or ***particle system***, but you have to prepare the mesh properly first.
[image]

Add an *UV Sphere* with default settings (I use these in this example) and delete the bottom half of it. Select the very first top edge loop, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Cursor to Selected*, then add a *circle* and set its vertices count to 6. Enable vertex *snapping tool* (magnet icon) and snap it to the default edge loop. Do the same with the lower edge loops, but this time add the *circle* with 6 more vertices. Delete the default loops with <kbd>X</kbd>.
[image]

Repeat the process until you get to the sixth edge loop (It should be 32-vertices default loop). Every lower edge loop should get 6 more vertices- I know it's a silly work but I don't know how to script ;P. Add a *cube* in the middle of the *sphere*.
[image]

In *Object Mode* select the *cube*, then the *sphere*, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>-->*Set Parent To*-->*Object*.
[image]

Select the half of the *sphere* and give it the ***Mirror*** modifier (Z axis).
[image]

Finally with the *sphere* selected go to the *Object Data* header (*Duplication* panel), select the ***Verts*** window and check the *Rotation* checkbox.
[image]

Comment: Thx, it was very helpful and helps me to replicate this effect in Unity! But I wonder, is there a script somewhere for creation those circles with perfect accuracy. Or a formula in case I want to create a sphere with more than 32 vertical loops.

Comment: @PlanetControl I am curious if the script may work in this case too :) (I've mentioned it in my answer). I've also asked a question about it: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78817/how-to-create-a-sphere-with-different-ring-vertex-count-by-scripting Hope some scripting magicans can aswer it :).

Comment: Thanks to the efforts of amazing coders here you can now edit the sphere's rings number and it all work perfect :). Please check it out: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78817/how-to-create-a-sphere-with-different-ring-vertex-count-by-scripting