# How to create a sphere with different ring vertex count by scripting?

Tags: mesh, scripting, edit-mode

This question is related to this one: [How to distribute the objects on a sphere evenly?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78736/how-to-distribute-the-objects-on-a-sphere-evenly) I wonder if there's a way to create a sphere, in which every vertex loop's count is decreased according to its vertical position by scripting (let's say every ring count starting from the top of the sphere to the midlle of it is decreased by 6 vertices- as pictured below)? Is there a way to create a sphere and define it's individual ring's count by scripting?

P.s. I don't know if a tittle of my question is right. If not feel free to change it.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

I think, there is no perfect solution to this problem, though:

[image]

What is the problem:

- Chords of each circle need to be regular in both directions (latitude, longitude)
- But this chords length need to correspond to a latitude of this sphere
- And this latitude may not correspond to an entire amount of the chord length

So the result is only an approximation.

The code without the UI:

```
import bpy
from math import pi, cos, sin

#Create a new mesh from a geometry 
def CreateMesh( scene, name, location, vertices, edges, polygons ):
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new( name )
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new( name, mesh )
    obj.location = location

    scene.objects.link( obj )
    scene.objects.active = obj
    obj.select = True

    mesh.from_pydata( vertices, edges, polygons )
    mesh.update()    

    return obj

#Merge new vertices (a ring) to previous one
def MergeGeometry( vertices, edges, newVertices ):
    base = len( vertices )
    vertices += newVertices
    newVerticesAmount = len( newVertices )
    if newVerticesAmount > 2:
        edges += [(base + i, base + int((i+1) % newVerticesAmount) ) for i in range( newVerticesAmount )]
    elif newVerticesAmount == 2:
        edges += [(base, base + 1)]
    return vertices, edges    

#Calculate a circle
def Circle( z, r, verticesAmount ):
    baseAngle = 2 * pi / verticesAmount
    return [(r * cos(i * baseAngle), r * sin(i * baseAngle), z) for i in range( verticesAmount )]

#Calculate the sphere
def HomogeneousSphereBySegments( segments, r ):
    vertices, edges = [], []

    if segments % 2 == 0:
        ringAmount = segments // 2
        baseAngle = pi / ringAmount
        chord = 2 * r * sin( pi / segments )
        arc = 2 * pi * r / segments
    else:
        #If odd we have to shift the angle from the 'equator'
        ringAmount = segments // 2
        baseAngle = pi / ringAmount
        chord = 2 * r * cos( baseAngle / 2 ) * sin( pi / segments )
        arc = 2 * pi * r * cos( baseAngle / 2 ) / segments

    #First pole
    vertices += [(0,0,-r)]

    for i in range( 1, ringAmount ):
        angle = (i * baseAngle) - (pi / 2)
        z = r * sin( angle )
        localR = abs( r * cos( angle ) )
        verticesAmount = int( 2 * pi * localR / arc )
        vertices, edges = MergeGeometry( vertices, edges, Circle( z, localR, verticesAmount ) )
        print( ringAmount, baseAngle, angle, z, localR )        

    #Second pole
    vertices += [(0,0,r)]

    return vertices, edges
```

Blend file with code usable as an operator (add mesh, 'Homogeneous Sphere'):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort. The fact you can easily edit the sphere's parameters via operator panel make it a perferct answer. Amazing!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`bmesh.ops.create_circle()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.create_circle) to add a circle to a mesh, then use [`bmesh.ops.translate()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.translate) to put it into position, unless you create a matrix and pass it to `create_circle`.

You use the [pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Other_forms_of_the_theorem) to get the size of each ring to get a spherical result.

And if you think the following math is out, it is because the diameter parameter for `create_circle` appears to actually be the radius.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from math import sqrt

ring_verts = [32,32,32,30,24,18,12,6]
radius = 1.0
step_size = radius / len(ring_verts)

def get_diameter(z):
    return sqrt(radius**2 - z**2)

bm = bmesh.new()
for i,v in enumerate(ring_verts):
    z = step_size * i
    diam = get_diameter(z)
    ret = bmesh.ops.create_circle(bm, cap_ends=False, diameter=diam, segments=v)
    bmesh.ops.translate(bm, verts=ret['verts'], vec=(0.0,0.0,z))

me = bpy.data.meshes.new("Mesh")
bm.to_mesh(me)
bm.free()

scene = bpy.context.scene
obj = bpy.data.objects.new("Object", me)
scene.objects.link(obj)
scene.objects.active = obj
obj.select = True
```