# apply same curve angle than other object

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I need to create a kid night light with lot of star shape hole, but I don't understand how can I get the stars to get the same angle that the sphere.

I played with simple deformation modifier but don't seems to manage it
How can I do that properly ? also as I need probably 20 stars around, will I need to do manually or can I do all in one?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78736/how-to-distribute-the-objects-on-a-sphere-evenly https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56535/how-to-make-a-spiked-sphere/56537 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65395/repetitive-carvings-holes-around-a-sphere https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3212/how-can-i-create-a-hollow-sphere-with-regularly-spaced-holes